# Problemas com AutoMapper e List

Tags: c#

Pessoal tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
            List<NFE_CABECALHOEntity> lista = new List<NFE_CABECALHOEntity>();

                Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<NFE_CABECALHO, NFE_CABECALHOEntity>(); });

            lista = Mapper.Map<List<NFE_CABECALHO> ,List<NFE_CABECALHOEntity>>(listaData);
```

porém não estou conseguindo obter os objetos do listaData, estou fazendo algo de errado?

Esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

Mapping types:
List`1 -> List`1
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Data.Entity.NFE_CABECALHO, Data, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Entity.Model.NFE_CABECALHOEntity, Entity, Version=1.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Comment: Está gerando erro ou o objeto vem vazio?

Comment: Desculpe, inclui o erro que esta apresentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<NFE_CABECALHO, NFE_CABECALHOEntity>(); });

var lista = Mapper.Map<List<NFE_CABECALHOEntity>>(listaData);
```

O Mapper pode estar se perdendo porque você está usando dois argumentos de tipo com um parâmetro só, aí talvez esteja chamando o método errado.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado :D